# Unity C# TouchScript - Overlapped collider detection issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I'm working on a 2D non-game application. I used TouchScript to have all the multitouch gesture but I have an issue. 
In the application, i have the ability to open a lot of popup that are draggable, pinch resizable and we can rotate them. 
These popup are made with UIPanel. I add a collider2D on them

The issue is that when 2 popup are overlapping, if i want to move the one on top, i will randomly hit the one on the back or the top one.
It i like the touch goes through the first collider to hit the one behind...

Comment: **I used TouchScript ** This can be solved by using the new Unity UI event system. You don't need the TouchScript Asset.

Comment: I'm pretty new on Unity so i'm gonna check this 
thank you

Comment: That's fine. New UI tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsZM3q74Q2k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answering to the comment on your question suggesting to use the UI event system:
If you just use unity's UI events, you won't get advanced gestures such as swipe, pinch, etc and will have to code it yourself.

If you need these gestures, Touchscript is working fine and is a good choice.

Now to your question: I had the same problem and solved it by putting the script "UILayer" on the camera, instead of "CameraLayer2D"